# Is there any way to isolate an app without using container under cygwin windows

Tags: docker, cygwin, containers, windows-server-2008, isolation

I am using cygwin under windows server 2008 to have linux capability (to some degree) and ssh and be able to run apps without using a gui.

On another server that is ubuntu 18.04 I use containers to some how isolate my apps so that when I run an app and it spawns child processes and probabley modifies file descriptors etc (and so now I can not keep track of which processes are running now) I can stop my app and all the mess that it has done, with just stopping the container.

Containers made starting and stopping an app a `clean` and simple way.

Is there any way to have such thing on windows (without using docker on windows)? by saying this I mean the **file** and **process** isolation and not network or other stuff.

Is it possible to only isolate processes so that i can get rid of them with a single command?
Is there any tool for that? particularly for cygwin under windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself come to the conclusion that using services and creating a service in windows would be the only way to manage an app without using a container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other languages but if you're using Python, it has a feature called **Virtual Environment** and developer can create and run applications in isolated environments. you can learn more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: no i want to isolate processes not files themselves.